# Delete from MySql table after limited time

Tags: php, mysql, sql-delete

I have a that that stored some posts, and I would like the to delete these posts after a limited time, like 1hour or something.

The thing is a have a site where you need to signup, and before you register you need du verify your email by click on a link that got send from the site. And that link is stored in this temporary table.

So thing is I want the post (which contain the link) to get deleted from there after a limited time.

the table

```
$createCommentsTable = "CREATE TABLE comments(
id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
inlagg_id INT,
namn VARCHAR(30),
kommentar VARCHAR(200),
date VARCHAR(40),
PRIMARY KEY (id)
)";
```

Comment: What, specifically, is the question here?

Comment: delete a post from a table after a specefied time

Comment: He wants do auto-delete entries once they're more than X minutes old.

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple options, the easiest is to add a insert trigger that purges old records.

```
delimiter |

CREATE TRIGGER comments_bi BEFORE INSERT ON comments

FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    DELETE FROM comments WHERE `date` < DATE_SUB( CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, '-1 hour' );
END;

|

delimiter ;
```

But the best choice would be to store this sort of transient data in a caching driver (like [memcache](http://php.net/manual/en/book.memcache.php)

Comment: where should i put this code? and what are `testref` and `test1`

Comment: You can run this in your database.  I have edited the response, they were from the example on mysql docs.

Comment: still don't understan where i should writhe code?

i wrote the code like this 
`$sql = "CREATE TRIGGER comments_bi BEFORE INSERT ON comments
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    DELETE FROM comments WHERE 'date' < DATE_SUB( CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, '-1 hour' );
END";

$result = mysql_query($sql, $conn) or die (mysql_error());
echo $resultTempMembersTable;`

there i create the database

Comment: and it dont work.... it says
`You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''-1 HOUR' ); END' at line 3`

Answer (score 0):

there is no need to use a temporary table at all.

you can send all the required fields in the verification link as well, sealed with some hash.

```
$secret = "35onoi2=-7#%g03kl";
$email = urlencode($_POST['email']);
$hash = MD5($_POST['email'].$secret);
$link = "http://example.com/register.php?email=$email&hash=$hash";
```

that's all.
no need to store anything, and thus to setup any events as well

Answer (score 0):

Old post but i thought it would need an alternative answer.

What i usually do when i need to delete temporary data (files, database entries etc.) is to create a CRON job. This is solution is only fit if your webhost allows and supports CRON jobs. In this instance each of the temp records should also be added with a timestamp used for determining if the entry should be removed.

For more information about CRON see: [CRON](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron)

Answer (score -1):

Take a look into http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-event.html. You can try to issue a statement like

```
CREATE EVENT myevent
ON SCHEDULE AT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + INTERVAL 1 HOUR
DO
   DELETE FROM comments WHERE id = [comment id];
```

Comment: is this code going to be on the same page where a make the table?

Comment: I was thinking about launching this statement just after inserting a new record (you need to put newly inserted id instead of [comment id])

Comment: Also, check documentation, different versions of mysql have a bit different requirements as to naming events.